# Installing C# Windows Form Application with Database on another system

Tags: c#, .net, database, winforms

I have developed a winform application in C#.net and using SQL Server 2008.
My application inserts and updates values into database.
Is it possible to  install the application on a another system which doesn't have sql server on it?

Comment: Yes, you can install it. It just won't work without db.

Comment: Well you just need to be sure, that the Database can be accessed externally and that your application has the right connection settings

Comment: Are the different systems supposed to be sharing the same data, or to have their own separate databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine using sql azure. Cloud based sql server. The database is never on the same physically computer. It's all down to the connection string.
With an on premise database you need to make sure the database allows external connections, maybe opening up firewall etc. then make sure the connection string is set correctly on the application to talk to external database.
You can even configure to change the connection string as required pointing at different databases depending on the individual requirements.
Scott

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. You can access the DB remotely by referring remote DB server in connection string.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, if you are looking to run the application on machine that is running on the same Domain as the SQL Server and has privileges to the SQL Server.